# QuickTime Player 10 doubles track duration

Tags: macos, audio, quicktime, m4a

My copy of QuickTime (10.5) on Mojave (10.14.6) is duplicating the duration of (some) tracks I open with it. It isn't modifying the files themselves; it's just the track window that displays twice the time it should. The entire second half is just silence.

[image]

Quitting QuickTime Player and reopening it doesn't help. Neither does restarting my computer.

QuickTime 7.6.6 (of which I have the Pro version) also does this.

It seems to happen only with m4a files, but not with all m4a files.

What's going on, and how can I fix it?

Comment: Use "quicklook" in Finder or iTunes or Elmedia to play it and see if it works fine there. Also, what is the file format ? I played some mp3 podcasts with and without the cover photo and they played fine, same 10.5 (935.3) version, 10.14.5

Comment: I think the file in the screenshot is an m4a. I’ll check the other files and get back to you. When you say quicklook, do you mean playing it from Finder by clicking on the play button on the icon when in icon view / the Get Info window? If so, that only plays the correct duration, so it must be a QuickTime issue.

Comment: I've checked, and all the tracks it does that to are m4a files. However, it doesn't do it to all m4a files.

Comment: @Rain Hey, did you find the origin of this issue? I'm experiencing it right now. Thanks.

Comment: No, still haven’t found it. Sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I experienced the exact same issue today and found that [`AVPlayerItem`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avplayeritem)[`.seekableTimeRanges`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avplayeritem/1386155-seekabletimeranges?language=objc) seems to return this incorrect duration.

#### Fix:

What fixed the issue for me was to rename the audio from `m4a`/`mp4`to the contained audio format `aac`.
E.g. `myCoolAudioFile.m4a`-> `myCoolAudioFile.aac`

#### Edit:

What seems to be the root problem here is that Apple cant handle all container formats (I had a DASH container which caused this problem), to actually fix the root cause of this issue [see here](https://github.com/ryanheise/just_audio/issues/753#issuecomment-1186321444)

Comment: This worked! Thanks! What a stupid bug on Apple's part...